# changing directory color in CLI

Tags: command-line, colors

Im having a hard time reading in blue colored text, whenever i work using cli, directory colors are by default **blue** or so, my co-worker changed it to blue.

how can i easily change the directory color only? like turn it to red or yellow, so it stands out and not hurt my eyes. blue text and black background makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: Your co-worker changed it to blue? It's by default blue (as you just mentioned)... What did you mean by that? I'm assuming you mean directory color in `ls`? Also, you could try using a white background (it makes things _so_ much easier for me ^^)

Answer (score 2):

Doing a quick google search (and some testing), I found out this solution: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2002-06/msg00594.html

So more or less, set the `LS_COLORS` environment variable to something like `di=31;1` (for red) or `di=33;1` for yellow.

Here is a list of colors (the part after `di=`) you can use: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html

Also, check this out for further information: http://www.bigsoft.co.uk/blog/index.php/2008/04/11/configuring-ls_colors

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the end of `~/.bashrc`:

```bsh
# colors:
PROMPT_BLUE=`tput setf 1`
PROMPT_GREEN=`tput setf 2`
PROMPT_CYAN=`tput setf 3`
PROMPT_RED=`tput setf 4`
PROMPT_MAGENTA=`tput setf 5`
PROMPT_YELLOW=`tput setf 6`
PROMPT_WHITE=`tput setf 7`
PROMPT_BLACK=`tput setf 8`

# prompt which shows  yellow path relative to Your home dir:
PS1='\[$PROMPT_YELLOW\]\w\[$PROMPT_GREEN\]:\[$PROMPT_WHITE\] '
```